# how to calculate the correct amount with decimal

Tags: web3js

I have total token `99,999,999.99999457`, It is `8 decimal`, but when I do like below I get `99999999`, I expected `99,999,999.99999457`:

```
  const decimals = await this.contract.methods.decimals().call();
  const decimalsBN = this.web3.utils.toBN(decimals);
  const divisor = this.web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimalsBN);
  const balanceWei = await this.contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call();
  const balanceWeiBN = this.web3.utils.toBN(balanceWei);
  return balanceWeiBN.div(divisor).toString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the official documentation](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/#usage) of `BN`:

> Note: decimals are not supported in this library.

Here, the term *decimals* refers to numeric values with digits after the decimal point (i.e., non-integers).

So in short, you'll need to `npm install bignumber.js`, and then in your script, the easiest way IMO:

```
const BigNumber = require("bignumber.js");
const balance = await this.contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call();
const decimals = await this.contract.methods.decimals().call();
const bn = new BigNumber(balance + "e-" + decimals);
return bn.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works with `web3` without adding any additional libraries for any value of `decimals`:

```js
const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call();
const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call();
const unit = Object.keys(web3.utils.unitMap).find(key => web3.utils.unitMap[key] === web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(web3.utils.toBN(decimals)).toString());
console.log( web3.utils.fromWei(balance, unit) );
```